# service discovery failed, except on first connect

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm connecting my Android phone to a HC-05 bluetooth module. It kinda works, I can get some I/O done, but I also get some errors. First error I want to deal with is that I get a **"Service Discovery Failed"** IO Exception every time I connect to my Bluetooth device, except the first time. Only after a reboot of the phone will it cleanly connect. So, I'd expect something left open, but the only thing I can think of is the socket, and I close that.

```
09-16 13:55:16.463 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus I/BluetoothSocket_MTK: [JSR82] Bluetooth Socket Constructor
09-16 13:55:16.463 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus I/BluetoothSocket_MTK: [JSR82] type=1 fd=-1 auth=false encrypt=false port=-1
09-16 13:55:16.466 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus I/BluetoothSocket_MTK: [JSR82] connect: do SDP
09-16 13:55:16.738 8085-8098/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus I/BluetoothSocket_MTK: [JSR82] SdpHelper::onRfcommChannelFound: channel=-1
09-16 13:55:16.757 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
09-16 13:55:16.757 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:813)
09-16 13:55:16.758 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:382)
09-16 13:55:16.758 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus.bluetooth$1.onItemClick(bluetooth.java:173)
09-16 13:55:16.758 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
09-16 13:55:16.758 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
09-16 13:55:16.759 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2812)
09-16 13:55:16.759 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3571)
09-16 13:55:16.759 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-16 13:55:16.759 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-16 13:55:16.759 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-16 13:55:16.759 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
09-16 13:55:16.760 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 13:55:16.760 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-16 13:55:16.760 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
09-16 13:55:16.761 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
09-16 13:55:16.765 8085-8085/ltd.arctura.laro_can_bus W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Restarting the HC-05 or the bluetooth on the phone both are not enough.

I have verified the UUID is correct by doing:

```
            ParcelUuid[] uuids=btHC05.getUuids();
            if (uuids != null) {
                msg(uuids[0].toString());
            } else {
                msg("No UUID!?");
            }
```

This yields the same UUID as I had configured.

I tried to do a .close on the socket, but that's not helping. I have no input or output streams to close.

The device is already paired and proved to work. I generally don't understand how the Connect() can throw a service discovery failed.. I wouldn't expect the connect() to do any discovery..

```
private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private boolean isBtConnected = false;
String address = null;
static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

and

```
        try {
            if (btSocket == null) {
                BluetoothDevice btHC05 = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);
                btSocket = btHC05.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                btSocket.connect();

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ConnectSuccess = false;
        }

        if (!ConnectSuccess)
        {
            finish();
        }
        else {
            msg("Connected.");

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("address",address);
            setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();

        }

    }
```

There is some more, but this is what is relevant.. It's a bit messy because I've been trialling-erroring a lot ;-)

Also, and this might be relevant. All this happens in a separate activity that gives the user a list of BT-devices to choose from, and then goes back to the Main_Activity.

Comment: `static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");` The UUID should not be fixed. It should be choosen from a list of "sensed" devices, from time to time. There are a ton of tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: I verified the UUID (and updated the question), so it seems the UUID is correct.